# Como salvar um atributo para imagem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework

Preciso salvar uma imagem e digamos que eu tenha algo como:

```
namespace Projeto.Models
{
    public class Usuario
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public String Nome { get; set; }

        public ? Foto { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Sendo um sistema web, onde o usuário poderia fazer Upload da imagem e ficar salva no sistema, o que eu precisaria para salvar e exibir a foto do usuário?

Comment: Você quer salvar aonde? De onde? Exibir onde? Você já tentou fazer alguma coisa? Se tentou, coloca o código.

Comment: @Ricardo É um sistema web, um usuário do sistema pode editar o perfil dele, enviar uma imagem da máquina dele e ficar salva no banco de dados ligado ao sistema. Não tentei, ouvir falar do tipo Blob, mas não sei direito como utilizar, não achei nada muito claro na internet.

Comment: O arquivo da foto tem que ficar no banco de dados ou pode ficar armazenado em uma pasta do servidor e o banco de dados so guardar o link para o arquivo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em um sistema ASP.NET MVC, o que você procura é o esquema clássico de *upload* de arquivos. Eu vou explicar para um arquivo só, e este esquema não serve apenas para fotos, mas serve como começo.

Primeiro, você irá salvar em *Model* o caminho do arquivo, e não o arquivo em si. Até dá pra salvar o arquivo no banco de dados, mas isso vai ficar muito complicado, e não é a ideia da resposta, então modifique seu *Model* para o seguinte:

```
namespace Projeto.Models
{
    public class Usuario
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public String Nome { get; set; }
        public String CaminhoFoto { get; set; } // Aqui é o que vai ser efetivamente salvo

        [NotMapped]
        public HttpPostedFileBase Foto { get; set; } // Este campo não é salvo. Serve apenas para a tela
    }
}
```

Feito isso, precisamos modificar o *Controller* para admitir a foto. Não sei como é seu *Controller*, mas vou colocar um clichê que deve atender:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Criar([Bind(Include="UserId,Nome,Foto")] Usuario usuario)
    {
        if (usuario.Foto != null && usuario.Foto.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string caminho = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Usuarios/"), usuario.Foto.FileName);
            usuario.Foto.SaveAs(caminho);
            usuario.CaminhoFoto = usuario.Foto.FileName;
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Aqui você salva o Model normalmente.
        }
    }
```

Note que tomei várias liberdades. Uma delas é determinar um diretório de *upload* chamado `Uploads` dentro da solução. Não precisa ser assim. Pode ser outro diretório. Fiz para fins de exemplo.

Agora, vamos à *View*:

```
@model Projeto.Models.Usuario

@using (Html.BeginForm("Criar", "Usuarios", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Foto, new { type = "file", @class = "form-control", accept = ".jpg,.jpeg,.png" })
}
```

Aí tem o mínimo para que tudo funcione. Se precisar de alguma coisa, é só dizer.

---

*EDIT*

É pré-requisito para a resposta que seja salvo em banco, então vou fazer alguns adendos.

### Model

```
namespace Projeto.Models
{
    public class Usuario
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public String Nome { get; set; }
        public byte[] ConteudoFoto { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public HttpPostedFileBase Foto { get; set; } // Este campo não é salvo. Serve apenas para a tela
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Criar([Bind(Include="UserId,Nome,Foto")] Usuario usuario)
    {
        if (usuario.Foto != null && usuario.Foto.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(usuario.Foto.InputStream))
            {
                usuario.ConteudoFoto = binaryReader.ReadBytes(usuario.Foto.ContentLength);
            }
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Aqui você salva o Model normalmente.
        }
    }
```

*View* fica igual.

Answer (score 2):

Depende do que quer fazer, se deseja que a foto mesmo esteja aí, provavelmente o caminho é usar [`Image`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). Mesmo que a foto seja armazenada em outro local pode querer carregá-la na memória para por nesta propriedade da classe chamada `Foto`. Tem métodos utilitários para isto.

Se só quiser usar uma referência para a foto que estará em um arquivo ou outro local, então basta usar uma `string` mesmo e nele terá a localização da foto (URI ou chave de onde está, por exemplo).

A questão do *upload* já é outra coisa. Provavelmente usaria o [`HttpPostedFileBase`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httppostedfilebase?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0) (que eu não sei se é uma boa ideia para códigos mais modernos em ASP.NET MVC). Tem um [exemplo completo](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/259/asp-net-mvc-5-with-ef-6-working-with-files) usando banco de dados com Entity Framework (não estou dizendo que isto é o adequado para você).